# Empty download file from django view

Tags: python, django, file, view, download

I am using django 1.11.2 and I want to have view with downloadable file. After click on link the file is downloading but file is empty and instead of png, I recieved empty txt file.

```
def download_file(request, uuid):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/force-download')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str(models.DownloadLink.objects.get(uuid=uuid).download_file.file)
    response['Content-Length'] = 'http://{}{}'.format(Site.objects.get_current(), models.DownloadLink.objects.get(uuid=uuid).download_file.file.url)    
    return response
```

**EDIT:**

value here `response['Content-Length']` is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/filer_public/49/54/4954a7bb-8ad3-4679-9248-bffc7d186ca8/photo-105221.jpeg`

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the file in `HttpResponse` constructor like this:

```
def download_file(request, uuid):
    file = models.DownloadLink.objects.get(uuid=uuid).download_file
    response = HttpResponse(file.file, content_type='application/force-download')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str(file.file)
    response['Content-Length'] = 'http://{}{}'.format(Site.objects.get_current(), file.file.url)    
    return response
```

From [HttpResponse docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#id3)

> content should be an iterator or a string. If it’s an iterator, it
>   should return strings, and those strings will be joined together to
>   form the content of the response. If it is not an iterator or a
>   string, it will be converted to a string when accessed.